# How can I call a function of an exported function of a module in another script? NodeJS

Tags: node.js, module, discord

I want to use a function, which is inside another function (function2) in another js file (2nd.js).

My current code looks something like this:

**1st.js**

```
module.exports = {
   function1(){
      function2(){
         //...
      }
   }
}
```

**2nd.js**

```
const { function2 } = require("1st.js")
function2()
```

This sadly doesn't work and I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: If it is not exported and not made available through some other means (e.g. function1 returns an object that has function2 as a property) you don't have access to it.

Comment: You can't get to function2 from outside of function1.  function2 is private to the scope of function1 (this is just how Javascript scope works).  If you want to be able to call it from anywhere else, you have to explicitly make it available outside of function1's scope and then export it or make it so you can call `function1()` and it will return function2 somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with *class* approach or some older syntax. Any of these approaches results in the same thing, after all, the *class* syntax in JavaScript is just a thing for programmers, and does not affect the code at all. It is called syntax sugar.

See in the example below how to solve your problem without classes:

**Export a object "container" with your functions:**
Just as you referred in your example, 1st.js

```js
export default {
  functionOne: () => {
    console.log("one");
  },

  functionTwo: (num) => {
    console.log(num);
  },

  functionThree: ({number}) => {
    console.log(number);
  },
}
```

**And import it with any name you want**
...and so on, 2nd.js

```js
import myFunctions from "../myFunctions";

const { functionOne, functionTwo, functionThree} = myFunctions;

functionOne();

functionTwo("two");

functionThree({number: "three"});
```